# Защита от спама Telegram.Bot

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

Пишу бота на C# (использую Long Polling) возникла задача защиты от спама сообщениями. Я пытаюсь решить это так:

```
    Dictionary<long, GuardModel> UserBanCounter = new Dictionary<long, GuardModel>();
    TimeSpan blockLimit = new TimeSpan(0,0,2);

public async Task HandleUpdateAsync(ITelegramBotClient botClient, Update update, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        try
        {
            if (update.Type != UpdateType.Message)
            {
                return;
            }
            if (UserBanCounter.ContainsKey(update.Message.From.Id))
            {
                if (UserBanCounter[update.Message.From.Id].Amount > 10)
                {
                    return;
                }
                if (UserBanCounter[update.Message.From.Id].Amount == 10)
                {
                    await botClient.SendTextMessageAsync(new(AdminID), $"Пользователь {update.Message.From.Username} заблокирован за спам");
                    UserBanCounter[update.Message.From.Id].Amount++;
                    return;
                }
                if (update.Message.Date - UserBanCounter[update.Message.From.Id].LastMessageTime < blockLimit)
                {
                    UserBanCounter[update.Message.From.Id].Amount++;
                }
                else
                {
                    UserBanCounter[update.Message.From.Id].Amount = 0;
                }
                UserBanCounter[update.Message.From.Id].LastMessageTime = update.Message.Date;
            }
            else
            {
                UserBanCounter.Add(update.Message.From.Id, new GuardModel(update.Message.Date));
            }
            .
            .
            .
```

Дело в том, что я не нашёл нигде поднятия данного вопроса и возможных способов его решения, но прохождение несколькольких логических конструкций прежде чем сделать return кажется крайне ресурсоёмким процессом, если речи идёт о спаме наскольких сотен сообщений в секунду.
Подскажите, есть ли знаете более элегантное решение. Заранее благодарю.

Comment: просто посчитайте количество сообщений за последний час или другой период времени, и если количество больше нужного - игнор сообщения

Comment: количество сообщений от текущего пользователя*

Comment: Что в вашем понимании "спам"? Ведь он бывает разный. Допустим, просто спамим одно сообщение без остановки; Или рекламное сообщение; Или и то и то разом. Вот, к примеру вам на почту пришло письмо, оно попало в папку "Спам", письмо одно, верно? Так что, "спам" имеет разные виды, и все это надо изучать, смотреть от чего конкретно нужно бороться. Если закидывают много сообщений, то как быстро? В минуту 1000 сообщений? Человек так может? Нет. Значит считаем, как быстро отсылаются сообщения, блокируем. А реклама? Ну обычно они имеют "шаблонность", под которую можно подстроится, например, нейронкой.

Comment: @iiKuzmychov проблема подхода которого вы предлагаете и того кода, который я кинул в том, что необходимо запоминать количество сообщений КАЖДОГО пользователя, к тому же чтобы "проигнорировать" сообщение спамера обработчику нужно пройти несколько логических конструкций прежде чем сделать return, что может быть крайне ресурсозатратно если речь идёт об отправке сразу нескольких десятков вредоносных сообщений в секунду с нескольких аккаунтов

Comment: @EvgeniyZ речь идёт о ddose командами бота и обычными сообщениями, к сожалению или к счастью, я пока не сталкивался с этим, но хочу быть готов, так как не нашёл в гугле толкового ответа и не смог сымитировать подобную проблему чтобы исследовать работу бота под подобной нагрузкой, я не знаю насколько хорошо отработает подход с "запоминанием" количества сообщений КАЖДОГО пользователя.

Comment: `необходимо запоминать количество сообщений КАЖДОГО пользователя` и почему это проблема?

Comment: А зачем вам запоминание "каждого"? Вам нужно лишь при получении нового сообщения смотреть кто написал, и временно запомнить это со временем отправки. Вам достаточно простого списка на сообщений 10 (зависит наверно от активности), если сообщений больше - удаляете первое, чтоб не перегружало. Ну и уже по этому буферу смотрите активность, если человек имеет условно 5 сообщений, интервал между которыми допустим меньше 1с, то добавляете его в базу и игнорируете, ну а если интервал большой, то с большой долью вероятности это простой человек. ДДОС - это то, чего руками не повторить)

Comment: @iiKuzmychov если записывать пользователя в БД, то с каждым его сообщением нужно обращаться к БД, та же проблема и c Dictionary или List. Необходимо вести поиск  пользователей на каждое полученное сообщение, которых может быть сотня в секунду при атаке, так как _забанить_ пользователя нельзя, его можно только игнорировать и так или иначе его сообщение прийдёться обработать

Comment: сообщения можно обработать и если оно превышает лимит, то не сохранять его в БД

Comment: @EvgeniyZ как я написал комментарием выше, проблема в поиске пользователся, которая будет происходить на каждое его сообщение

Comment: @iiKuzmychov но чтобы найти уже _забаненного_ пользователся и _проигнорить_ его необходимо найти в БД при получении каждого сообщения, что на мой взгляд невероятно долго, вам не кажеться, если я не прав или чего-то не понимаю, то поправьте меня

Comment: 10 раз в секунду записать в простой `List` - это не очень затратная штука. Повторю, вам не надо постоянно писать, вам достаточно 10 последних сообщений, по которым определяете, спам или нет. Если спам, то в последующем просто игнорируете, без какого-либо добавления, а лучше и вовсе забанить силами телеграмма. Если речь про то, что вы своими силами забанили, и каждое последующее сообщение лезете в базу, чтоб проверить в бане человек или нет, а их сотни в секунду, то просто кэшируйте данные, раз спросили из базы, сохранили список, а дальше если в списке человек - игнор, если нет - подсчет.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ если знаете, как забанить пользователя в боте посредством телеграмма, дайте знать

Comment: @EvgeniyZ может я чего-то не понимаю, поправьте меня если так. На перебор коллекции из 10 элементов у меня ушло 14мс, предположим что недоброжелатели спамят 72 сообщения в секунду(может я перебарщиваю, но такое же возможно, теоретически), тогда на обработку всех сообщений отправленных за секунду уйдёт больше секунды и бот ляжет, вы согласны? Конечно, обработчик работает в асинхронном режиме, многопоточность, все дела(к сожалению слабо шарю), но все равно

Comment: Почему он должен лечь я не пойму? Боты всегда пишутся асинхронно, каждый пользователь должен быть отдельной "задачей", которая отдельно выполняется, и если вам разом напишет 100 человек, и вы просто читаете из листа в памяти, который содержит минимальное число элементов, то будет вам условно 14мс на всю работу, не, если вы ставите в очередь, и каждый у вас делает +14мс, то да, это косяк с вашей стороны. Если вы хотите оптимизации, то `HashSet` вам в помощь, будет O(1). Сайты огромные по сотни тысяч запросов обрабатывают разом, а у вас бот...

Comment: Видел был вопрос про бан - я не пользуюсь телеграмм (не люблю его), поэтому как он работает, сказать не могу. Документация дает такой метод: [banChatMember](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#banchatmember), но банит он все, я не знаю, но в теории подойти должен.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Спасибо, что поделились вашим мнением.

Comment: EvgeniyZ вам абсолютно правильно написал, поиск элемента в коллекции по ключу в словаре, хеш-сэте или базе данных это всегда невероятно быстрая операция. Любые опасения по производительности из головы лучше не брать, а проверять замерами